# Selenium | Chromedriver Android

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I can't find the answer to this question anywhere.

Chromedriver has a page that tells you that it can be installed on android. But I didn't really understand anything, I didn't find the file for the jump and the installation, too. I downloaded a file for linux, I thought maybe Google meant it, but no, it doesn't open in termix.

Please, if you know or can find the answer, then share. I will be incredibly happy.

And if there are no options, how to do it. That is, does anyone have instructions for installing a NORMAL and full-fledged Linux on Samsung A5?

Comment: Do you want to install `chromdriver` in your Android ? Or do you want to install `Linux` in Samsung A5 ? Please clarify ?

Comment: I want to install chromedriver, but if this is not possible, then linux

Comment: Checkout this will might help [https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689253/11863448]

Comment: Yes, I've seen it. But my point is that the python telegram bot script is installed on the phone. And there he parses information from the site, you can't use requests, because you need to click on the buttons + scroll through the pages. Because of all this, I need the phone to be independent of the computer.

Comment: So I need chromedriver to be exactly on a phone without adb.